# Sql Server Add Text in result based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table is like this

```
--------------------------
-- id -- name -- status --
--------------------------
-- 1  -- boy  -- active --
-- 2  -- ball --inactive--
--------------------------
```

What I want to achieve is that list of name + a string depend on the status

Something like this:

```
SELECT name + if(status == 'active'){ 'Active' }else{ 'In Active' } FROM table
```

So result will come like

```
-------------------
-----  name -------
-------------------
-- boy Active    --
-- ball In Active--
-------------------
```

Comment: Use CASE instead of IF.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `CASE` expression to return the desired string literal. You can then use `+` operator to concatenate `name` with the literal returned by the `CASE`:

```
SELECT name + CASE WHEN status = 'active' THEN 'Active' 
                   ELSE 'InActive' 
              END
FROM table
```

If you are using SQL Server 2012+, then you can use [**`IIF`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx):

```
SELECT name + IIF ( status = 'active', 'Active', 'InActive' )
FROM table
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I just cast the name and put your code. :)